# Is it possible to get a stack trace for chrome console warning?

Tags: google-chrome, console, reactjs

React warned me about bad state logic somewhere:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

When I click the line number, it points to a `console.warn` line in the React source code. How can i see where in my code the warning is coming from? Is there a way to get a stack trace from `warn`?

It's hard to track down when there's > 20 distinct components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you are inspecting the react source code in chrome, you can click on a line number to add a break point.

Once you refresh the page, the debugger will halt at the given line and via the call stack on the right you then can see how you got there.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome show stack traces for warnings:
[image]

But chromium does not:
[image]